# how to handle the datatable column value is

Tags: c#, linq

I want to check lastlogindate column is null or not.If it is not null i want convert the object into date time format otherwise i want to return as null using conditional operator or linq.

public class UserBase
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

```
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLogOnDate { get; set; }

    public string Active { get; set; }

    public string PlantId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

the above is my class and methods

```
user = datatable.AsEnumerable().Select(row =>
                    new EGDataStructure.UserBase
                    {
                        UserName = row.Field<string>("User Name"),
                        FirstName = row.Field<string>("First Name"),
                        LastName = row.Field<string>("Last Name"),
                        Email = row.Field<string>("Email ID"),
                        PhoneNo = row.Field<string>("Phone No"),
                        MobilePhone = row.Field<string>("Mobile No"),
                        GroupName = row.Field<string>("Group Name"),
                        LastLoginDate=row.Field<DateTime>("Last Logged Date")
                       LastLogOnDate =  if ( LastLoginDate != DBNull.Value)??Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<DateTime>("Last Logged Date"),CultureInfo.InvariantCulture):Null,

                        Active = row.Field<string>("active"),
                        UserId = row.Field<string>("userId")
                    }).ToList();
                }
```

Comment: LastLoginDate =row.Field<DateTime>("Last Logged Date") == null? null: Convert.TodateTime(row.Field<DateTime>("Last Logged Date"))...Did you try this ?

Comment: Do try what @AnkeshKumar mentioned, since you cannot reference another variable e.g. `LastLoginDate` in the `new {` statement `if ( LastLoginDate != DBNull.Value)`.

Comment: ya i tried but i am getting type of  conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between <null> and system.Datetime

Comment: You cannot set a DateTime object to null.  The best you can do is to use new DateTime().  This will give a date of 1/1/1 which is out of family.  Do to test if a DateTime is default you later have to do something like if date.year > 2000.

Comment: is it possible for you to change the property like public DateTime? 
 LastLogOnDate { get; set; } so that null value can be assign ?

Comment: ya i changed the property DateTime? LastLogOnDate { get; set; }  but still getting the error

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a structure, so you gonna need `Nullable<DateTime>` (or shortform `DateTime?`).

```
public DateTime? LastLogOnDate { get; set; }
```

and

```
LastLogOnDate = row.Field<DateTime?>("Last Logged Date")
```

In case you want to explicitely distinguish between `null` and other values, for example because the field is originally a string and needs conversion:

```
LastLogOnDate = row.IsNull("Last Logged Date")
    ? (DateTime?)null
    : Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<string>("Last Logged Date"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
```